# Connect BM800 condenser microphone to LG-OK55 Karaoke System

Tags: microphone, amplifier, live, monitoring

I just bought BM800 condenser microphone to play karaoke. I have LG-OK55 Karaoke System.

When I plug BM800 into my PC, it works but with a high latency.

If I plug BM800 directly into LG-OK55, it doesn't work at all (other microphone works on LG-OK55).

Do you think BM800 can work on LG-OK55 if I put a phantom power ?
I want to buy phantom power device but I want to be sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shock-mounted condenser mic is an odd choice for karaoke. Can't be hand-held & will have little to no feedback rejection.

Yes, it needs phantom power, but by the time you've bought the power supply & new XLR-XLR mic cable, you could have got a cheap hand-held dynamic mic which would be far better suited to the job.